# Keras output layer gives unexpected error

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network

I am using Keras for a binary classification problem. I am using the following adaptation of LeNet:

```
lenet_model = models.Sequential()
lenet_model.add(Convolution2D(filters=filt_size, kernel_size=(kern_size, 
                kern_size), padding='valid', input_shape=input_shape))
lenet_model.add(Activation('relu'))
lenet_model.add(BatchNormalization())
lenet_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(maxpool_size, maxpool_size)))
lenet_model.add(Convolution2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(kern_size, 
                    kern_size), padding='valid'))
lenet_model.add(Activation('relu'))
lenet_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(maxpool_size, maxpool_size)))
lenet_model.add(Convolution2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(kern_size, 
                    kern_size), padding='valid'))
lenet_model.add(Activation('relu'))
lenet_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(maxpool_size, maxpool_size)))
lenet_model.add(Flatten())
lenet_model.add(Dense(1024, kernel_initializer='uniform'))
lenet_model.add(Activation('relu'))
lenet_model.add(Dense(512, kernel_initializer='uniform'))
lenet_model.add(Activation('relu'))
lenet_model.add(Dropout(0.2))
lenet_model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='uniform'))
lenet_model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

lenet_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(), 
                        metrics=['accuracy'])
```

But I am getting this:

```
ValueError: Error when checking model target: expected activation_6 to have shape (None, 1) but got array with shape (1652, 2). It gets resolved if I use 2 in the final Dense layer.
```

Comment: Then what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that in your preprocessing steps, you have used functions to turn your numerical class labels into categorical ones, i.e., representing numerical classes in the one-hot coding scheme (in Keras, `to_categorical(y, num_classes=2)` would do this job for you).

Since you are dealing with a binary problem, if the original labels are 0s and 1s, the coded categorical labels would be 01s and 10s (in labels coded in the one-hot scheme, counting from right to left, the *n*th digit would be 1 if the numerical class for this instance is *n* while the rest of that label would be 0). This would explain why your data dimension in the error traceback is `(1652, 2)`.

However, since you have set the output dimension in your model to 1, your output layer would expect the desired labels in data to be of 1 digit only, which would correspond to the raw data before you applied any preprocessing steps mentioned above.

So, you could fix this problem either by taking out the preprocessing for the labels or changing the output dimension to 2. If you stick with using categorical labels coded in the one-hot fashion, you should also switch the sigmoid activation in the last layer to softmax activation since sigmoid only deals with binary numerical classes, i.e., 0 or 1. For a binary classification problem, these two choices should not differ in performance much.

One thing worth mentioning is that you should also pay attention to the cost function you use when you compile this model. Generally speaking, categorical labels work the best with cost functions like categorical crossentropy. Especially for multi-class classification (more than 2 classes) problems where you would have to use categorical labels together with a softmax activation, categorical crossentropy should pretty much be your default choice since it has many benefits over some other common cost functions such as MSE and raw error count.

One of the many benefits of categorical crossentropy would be the fact that it penalizes a "very confident mistake" much more than the case where the classifier "almost got it right", which makes sense. For example, in a binary classification setting using categorical crossentropy as the cost function, a classifier that is 95% sure that a given instance is of class 0 whereas the instance actually belongs to class 1 would be penalized more than a classifier that is 51% percent sure when it made this mistake. Some other cost functions like raw error count are insensitive to how "sure" the classifier is when it makes decisions and those cost functions only take into consideration the final classification result, which essentially means losing a great deal of useful information. Some other cost functions such as MSE would give more emphasis on the wrongly classified instances, which is not always the desired feature to have.

Comment: Thanks Michael, so this issue occurred  because I was using categorical labels.

Comment: @FJ_Abbasi no problem:)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest first check the dimensionality of your data. The training dataset target is 2 dimensional, but the model takses 1 dimensional data.

You have set `lenet_model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='uniform'))` to accept 2 dimensional data. You need to set the final dense layer shape such that it accepts target shape `(None,2)`

`lenet_model.add(Dense(2, kernel_initializer='uniform'))` is what it should be else preprocess your data such that target data is 1 dimensional data.

Consider reading the documentaion before writing the code next time.